# print last n no of lines before 1st n

Tags: python

hey how can we print the 2nd half part of string before 1st part like if a string is of 2n lines then write last n lines followed by first n lines.

eg:

INPUT:

my name,

saurabh singh

OUTPUT:

saurabh singh

my name,

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code generation service. Please show your attempts at solving the solution and describe where you are stuck rather than just posting your whole assignment.

Comment: Don't ask your NPTEL programming assignments in StackOverflow! They are given for your practice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If its 2n lines, do as shown below

```
temp = str_inp.split("\n")
print(temp[len(temp)/2:] + temp[:len(temp)/2])
```

Comment: bt how can we print these lines

Comment: using print statement